# Retrieving borrower name based on borrowertype id from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, `Customer` and `RegisteredCustomer`.

`Customer` table has the first and last name of customers including the family members stored against each `Residentid`.

The `RegisteredCustomer` has the `CustomerType` as 1 being primary and 2 being `FamilyMembers`.

I want to select both the primary and `Familymember` displayed side by side.

```
Select FirstName, LastName 
from Customer
Inner Join RegisteredCustomers on Customer.Customerid = RegisteredCustomer.Customerid 
                               and CustomerType = 1
```

How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: What goes wrong with the query you posted? How does the result differ from what you want?

Comment: I get the first name  and last name of the primary customer. I want the First and Last name of the family members as well displayed in the same row.

Comment: Looks like you want `pivot`. Search for that

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Select a.Customerid,FirstName, LastName,b.CustomerType from
(Select Customerid,FirstName, LastName from Customer) as a

left join 

(select Customerid,cusdescription,CustomerType from RegisteredCustomers)as b
on a.Customerid = b.Customerid where CustomerType = 1
```

Hope it could help.